# Логика сохранения тегов для поста. PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно в админке при создании поста добавить к нему теги.
Есть три таблицы в БД `posts, tags, post_has_tags`. Связь `belongsToMany()`
Обычно реализовывал так:

- На фронте на input вешал js библиотеку например Tagify.
- При вводе названия отправлял запрос на бек для поиска подходящих тегов.
- На беке принимал массив с названиями тегов і через whereIn('name', array $tagNames) получал существующие теги.
- Не существующие сохранял в Бд и получал их идентификаторы
- Дальше привязывал новые и существующие теги по идентификаторам к посту `$post->tags()->attach(array_merge($tags, $new_tags))`

КОд согранения на беке:

```
public function syncTags(array $tagNames): array
{
    $tagModel = $this->tags()->getModel();
    $existsTags = $tagModel::query()
                           ->whereIn('name', $tagNames)
                           ->get(['id', 'name']);

    $newTags = array_diff($tagNames, $existsTags->pluck('name')->toArray());

    $prepareInsert = array_map(function ($value) {
        $title = trim($value);

        return [
            'name' => $title,
            'slug' => Str::slug($title)
        ];
    }, $newTags);

    $tagModel::insert($prepareInsert);
    $attachTags = $tagModel::query()->whereIn('name', $newTags)
                           ->get(['id', 'name']);

    $ids = $existsTags->merge($attachTags)->pluck('id')->toArray();

    return $this->tags()->sync($ids);
}
```

На нынешнем проекте меня попросили переписать данный функционал, аргументировав это тем что нужно передавать на бек только идентификаторы так как поиск по именам не есть ОК. также и при поиске по slug. Есть вероятность, что либо, из-за ошибки кодировки либо еще чего мы создадим существующий тег.
На вопрос что делать с тегом которого нет в БД - Ответ: Создать метод API или с помощью livewire сохранять этот тег и возвращать его идентификатор на фронт и при сохранении поста отправлять только идентификаторы.
Либо при сохранении поста отправлять массив типа `[new_tags=>[new_tag1], old_tag=>[tag1, tag2]]`.

Я посмотрел библиотеки для сохранения подобным вариантом на беке но там только варианты где принимают неймы а не идентификаторы.
Например в библиотеке spatie/laravel-tags.
И вот я пытаюсь розобратся почему и при каких обстоятельствах такое реально..
Может кто тоже так делает буду благодарен за пояснения

*Дополнено*

**Реализовал с передачей идентификаторов.** Как и ожидалось реализация сложнее.
При отправке формы на сохранение я отправляю идентификаторы для существующих тегов и названия новых в отдельном инпуте tags[1,2,3], new_tags[tag 1, tag 2]
После перезагрузки страницы при не удачной валидации я получаю только идентификаторы существующих тегов. Нужно для них откуда то взять имена. Отдельным запросом!? Теги подтягиваются при вводе  названия путем Ajax.
Отправлять пробовал [Old Name=>1, New New name=>null]. Но js библиотека понимает только два формата либо только имена, либо подготовленный массив который через инпут не передать.
Отсюда нужно реализовывать конвертацию. Получать существующие теги по ID.
Как по мне, подход сомнительный и не рациональный.

Почему прихожу к такому выводу!?
Чем отличается получения тегов при вводе по имени (путем ajax) от поиска для сохранения после отправки формы. Как по мне ничем. Что в первом, что во втором случае получаем идентификаторы по имени. В первом при поиске, во втором после отправки формы.

Comment: Ошибка кодировки - это бред от каких-то дедов, которые застряли в win-1251. Уже всё давно в utf-8 и никогда ничего не летит. Отрпавлять только id тегов - идея здравая, но вы же скорее всего так и делали (иначе как вы pivot таблицу бы создали). Библиотека вам тут не нужна, у вас и так уже есть реализация, её немного надо просто докрутить

Comment: Я добавил в опись код сохранения на беке.
Я с фронта получаю Названия тегов. 
Для передачи идентификаторов нужно как то придівівать отправку названия нового тега которого не подтянуло при вводе в БД.
Тоесть при отправке идентификаторов я мог бы проверить есть ли тег з id=1 в бд. Но как передать в одном массиве еще и название нового тега...

Вопрос даже не в том как передать. Мне его еще нужно этот масив скормить библиотеке после ошибки валидации.  old('tags') (з перезагрузкой страницы)
Добавля

Comment: А вы на лету подвязываете теги к посту или после кнопки сохранения? Если на лету, то да, потребуется передавать 2 массива. Если нет - сначала отправляйте тег на проверку и создавайте его, возвращая id и собирая их в массив внутри фронтенда (если требуется перезагрузка, можете в localStorage сохранять), а при сохранении передавайте только id тегов.

Comment: Видимо я не так вопрос поставил.
Меня интересовало в чем разница между передачей идентификаторов при отправки всей формы и при отправке имен тегов. Ведь поиск в базе при вводе первых символов тегов всеровно идет по имени. И для меня ето кажеться изобретанием велосипеда.
Либо я что то непонимаю, что не исключено

Comment: Ну вы уже точно знаете, что именно это за теги, отдавать имена Вам уже не нужно. Дальше у вас pivot таблица содержит id тега и id записи -- если вы передаете сами id, то достаточно просто через `attach` их добавить, а если имена, то тогда придётся делать запрос на лишнее доставание информации с базы (а это уже лишнене время на запрос). Потом даже если запрос нужно сделать, чтобы найти валидные теги по id, то поиск по числам работает быстрее (на primary key так вообще индексы стоят), а полнотекстовый поиск работает сильно медлннее, когда у вас будет в базе 2 миллиона тегов -- сами поймёте :)

Comment: Дописал  коментарий после реализации в посте